# Pass Python keyword as an argument?

Tags: python, twitter

I'm currently developing a Python script that uses the Twitter Streaming API.

The problem is that when I call the `stream.user()` it asks for an argument like `stream.user(with=followings)`, but Python detects the 'with' as a keyword and gives me a syntax error. Is there any way to bypass this?

**Update:**

Here is the Twitter doc: https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/userstreams#Data_from_accounts_the_user_follows, it says that I need to use 'with=followings' if I want to get tweets from accounts the user follows.

**Update 2:**

Here's the code:

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonStreamer

class Streamer(TwythonStreamer):

    def on_success(self, data):

        if 'text' in data:
            user  = '@' + data['user']['screen_name']
            tweet = ': ' + data['text']

    def on_error(self, status_code, data):
        print status_code
        self.disconnect()

stream = Streamer('XXX',
                'XXX',
                'XXX',
                'XXX')

stream.user(with=followings)
```

Comment: What? There's no way a Python library could be asking for this, since it is a syntax error.

Comment: The Twitter streaming API is an HTTP API.  You must be using some Python library.  What is it?

Comment: Then you're going to need to show more of your code. I can't see any reference to `stream.user` in the Twython streaming examples; what is stream and user here? And what docs are you using that tell you to pass `with` as a kwarg?

Comment: l = StreamListener()
streamer = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth, listener=l)
    streamer.userstream(_with='followings')

Comment: @OscarColon, i think you meant you want to use tweepy package. please see my suggested answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer after looking at Twython documentation. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
Looking at https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/00d9d6a7666267bc305a2ceccb642ef79a1555c7/twython/streaming/types.py

links to: https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/get/user

```
def user(self, **params):
```

Notice the double star **

> If the form *identifier is present, it is initialized to a tuple
>   receiving any excess positional parameters, defaulting to the empty
>   tuple. If the form **identifier is present, it is initialized to a new
>   dictionary receiving any excess keyword arguments, defaulting to a new
>   empty dictionary.

Try this:

```
params = {'with' : 'followings'}

stream.user(**params)
```

"with" is indeed a keyword in python

```
>>> import keyword
>>> keyword.iskeyword('with')
True
```

Comment: Nope, gives me this error: `TypeError: user() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

Comment: then you can't use any argument in `user()`

Comment: @Alexander problem was keyword `with` but `user() takes exactly 1 argument ` so it can't be done this way. (`stream.` is first and only argument for `user()`)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't specified in your question but i assumed you wanted to listen to all the tweets from a specific user. in this case you may work with tweepy streaming in the following manner :

```
l = StreamListener()
streamer = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth, listener=l)
streamer.userstream(_with='followings')
```

you may read more in [here](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/userstreams#userstream)